# Eclipse plugin: Copy/Export dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a plugin that is in need of some .dll-files. As I debug the Eclipse-Applicatoin and try to load these .dll files I receive a `FileNotFoundException` since the application does not look inside the project folder but in the actual Eclipse folder it is running in.

So it is not `C:\eclipseworkspace\myproject\fileineed.dll` it is `C:\eclipse\fileineed.dll` instead.

Of cource I just could copy that .dll there and that's it but I am sure I can tell Eclipse to export these files to the debugging Eclipse.

Does anyone know how?

Comment: you maybe look at ANT-Build Script there you can specify which files should be copied with your project

Answer (score 0):

Please read the paragraph about "Native code and class loaders" at http://www.eclipsezone.com/articles/eclipse-vms/. That will tell you the most important steps:

- Put the DLL at the root of the plugin project.
- Include it in build.properties.
- Use either System.loadLibrary() or OSGI headers to finally get the DLL loaded at runtime.